# Angular - How to create a reusable "create record" form or partial that pushes a record onto the parent scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

My Angular setup: I have an "Edit Invitation" state which has a single invitation as its scope. The invitation has a list of guests - controlled by a guestList controller - which are iterated over in my view.

```
<div ng-controller="guestListCtrl as guestList">
    <div ng-repeat="guest in invitation.guests">
    {{ guest.name }}
    </div>
</div>
```

At the end of my list, there is a button to add a new guest. This toggles a small form that allows users to save a new guest record.

```
<form name="addGuest" class="form" ng-submit="addGuest.$valid && guestList.addGuest(guestList.newGuest)" novalidation>
```

This all works great - My controller handles adding a new guest and pushing the new guest onto its parent guestList.guests scope.

BUT, on my Admin page, I essentially have the same setup. I show a list of guests, controlled by the guestList controller, and it allows me to add a new guest via the same form. The only difference is that the HTML in my list of guests is very different here - it uses different HTML elements, has different CSS classes, and employs a directive to allow admins to edit fields on click.

My question is - is there some way for me to extract the "add new record" portion of this process into its own partial or directive, so I don't need to re-write my "add new guest" form and logic each time?

My first thought was to create an element directive:

```
<new-guest></new-guest>
```

Here's the directive code:

```
angular.module('app.directives').directive('newGuest', ['Guest', '$stateParams', function(Guest, $stateParams){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: 'directives/new-guest.html',
    bindToController: true,
    controllerAs: 'newGuestCtrl',
    controller: function() {
      var vm = this
      vm.newGuest = { "invitation_id": $stateParams.id };

      vm.addGuest = function(newGuest){
        Guest.create({guest: newGuest}, function(response) {
          //this is where I would push my new guest onto parent scope if I could
        });
        vm.newGuest = {};
      };

    }
  }
}]);
```

This works great re: adding the record to my database, but I don't know how to push the new record onto its parent scope outside the directive - guestList.guests. I know I could do this by creating a new directive to house my list of guests, then pushing onto that directive's scope, but I'm not sure that makes much sense since my Admin and User versions of the guest list use entirely different HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Add the guests list as a two-way binding to your directive :

```
scope: {
    list: '='
}
```

in your directive definition creates the binding and

```
<new-guest list="guestList.guests"></new-guest>
```

in your directive tag feeds it the guest list.

2) Push the new guest in your callback, as you correctly suggested

```
scope.list.push(newGuest);
```

This should ensure that the guestList.guests list stays up to date.

Comment: Wow, you are absolutely right! Funny thing, I tried that earlier and it didn't work - probably because of a typo or naming issue. Just set it all up like you have above, and it worked like a charm. Thank you!